# What is the order of execution of the binded classes in google guice

Tags: java, web, guice

I've something like the following:

```
public class ValidationModule extends AbstractModule {
 @Override
 protected void configure() {
    Multibinder<Validator> validatorMultibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(),
        Validator.class, Names.named("mainValidators"));
    validatorMultibinder.addBinding().to(FirstValidator.class);
    validatorMultibinder.addBinding().to(SecondValidator.class);
 }
}
```

I'm a newbie to google/guice and I would like to understand the order of these validator `validate` function will be executed. Are they going to run from top to bottom or the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

After running the module in the application I have found that the object that I bounded to "mainValidators" was holding the classes in the order from top to bottom. So when I iterated over them they were in the following order.

1. FirstValidator
2. SecondValidator